# CGFloat * 2 compiles, CGFloat * Variable where variable is an integer fails

Tags: swift

I have to wrap my ints in `CGFloat()` to compile in Swift 2.3

If I just did `* 2`, then it would compile. Why does this happen?
Is this fixed in Swift 3?

```
var multiplier = CGFloat(3)      
let y = collectionView.frame.origin.y + (cellSize() * multiplier)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift does not directly support mixed type arithmetic. Check what the type of `2` is in Swift, it's probably not what you assume. Your use of `CGFloat()` is converting the value so the operands of `*` have the same type.

HTH

Comment: Yeah, it's just odd the compiler doesn't pick up on that from 1 line above

Comment: When you just define a variable to be `2` what type should the compiler associate with the variable? As you suggest it *could* leave it as unknown for the time being and wait until it is later used to fix its type. However what if it is later used in multiple places with different types (or possible types)? What error should then be produced? It is a design choice and adds complexity to the compiler for debated benefit. Some languages/compilers do support more flexibility, currently Swift (an ever moving target so it could change...) does not even for "simple" cases like yours.

Answer (score 1):

type inference. When you write out * 2 without explicitly declaring it an int Swift infers it to be a CGFloat. However when you've already declared it to be an int you can't multiply a CGFloat with an Int.