# How to fix 'Expression type 'CGSize' is ambiguous without more context' in swift?

Tags: swift, cgsize

This is my code :

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageScroll: UIScrollView!
...
imageScroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: imageScroll.visibleSize.width * 5, height: imageScroll.visibleSize.height)
```

It's OK.

If I chang it as below:

```
let ct = 5

imageScroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: imageScroll.visibleSize.width * ct, height: imageScroll.visibleSize.height)
```

It prompt an error : Expression type 'CGSize' is ambiguous without more context

When I post my question, stackoverflow prompt me a similar question: [How to fix "Expression type '@lvalue CGRect/CGSize' is ambiguous without more context"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54464103/how-to-fix-expression-type-lvalue-cgrect-cgsize-is-ambiguous-without-more-co)

I changed let to var, the error is same.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44425463/1187415

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `ct = 5` is inferred as type `int`.

`imageScroll.visibleSize.height` the height property is a `CGFloat`

They need to be the same type so if you change your code to this it should work

```
let ct: CGFloat = 5
```

Comment: This answer doesn't fully explain the error. The reason you get the error is that `CGSize` has initializers that take either `Int`, `Double`, or `CGFloat`. Since `ct` is an `Int` and `imageScroll.visibleSize.height` is a `CGFloat`, the compiler can't assume whether you intend the result of the `*` operator to be `Int` or `CGFloat` so it can't decide which `CGSize` initializer to use.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy, I thought that was implied (I did add the possible initializers but then decided against it). Thanks for clarification